# WordPress 5.3 Version issue

Tags: mysql, wordpress, version

I have updated the current wordpress site to version 5.3 in which i have added the new google captcha keys ( Site and Secret ) for the recaptcha, but the recaptcha tag generator is not showing in the contact form 7 when we create the form, in older version of wordpress ( 4.9.* ) it is working. Need Recaptcha for the site.
{ With older version of wordpress { 4.9.8 } it is working fine. }
Without recaptcha form is working fine.
Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: more of a serverfault question that stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Ninja Forms, and getting Site and Secret keys from reCAPTCHA V2  (yours is reCAPTCHA V3), solved my issue.